# Twig variable accessible in embedded JS but not when referencing external JS

Tags: javascript, twig

I'm pretty new to Twig so this may be elementary, but I fail to see why this will not work.

For example in my twig template I put my JS after my html

```
console.log('{{ vars.url' }});
```

This will print the url as I expect.

However, if I put that exact line in its own file and instead reference it as

```
<script src="js/weather-utilities.js"></script>
```

I would expect it to also have access to the twig variables, but it doesn't.

Anyone able to tell me what I fail to understand here?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Twig on the server (PHP)? If so, to get your Twig variables in a separate JS file, you would have to render it with Twig which I don't recommend. You should use AJAX to request `vars.url` from the server instead. Another approach would be to have some kind of config method in your JS file that you call at the bottom of the HTML template e.g. `<script>WeatherUtilities.config('{{ vars.url }}');</script>`.

Comment: Yes, I use the html template is rendered with twig(PHP). I'm primarily wondering why the twig variables are accessible if I embed the script in the html template, but not if it is referenced. Perhaps my understanding of how referencing JS works is off; is it wrong to think of it as 'inserting' it into the template?

Comment: The server says something like "when the user asks for `/about`, give the user this twig template with these variables in it" whereas when you ask the server for JavaScript files (or images, CSS, etc) it will give you the literal content of that file (unless your server application pushed requests for .js files through Twig as well, which is not likely).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I tried the aforementioned config approach and it seems neat and tidy enough for my purpose :)